# python - appending string to a list nontype error

Tags: python, list, append

I am writing a hangman game, and I want to add the user inputted char to the list of guesses. (Ignore the no error checking). I, however, continue to get this annoying - "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append' ".

My code that throws the error on guessList[] within the while loop.

```
import random


wordlist=["chapman","machine","learning","computer","python","california",
      "jellybeans","coffee","laboratory","disneyland","library", "freedom",
      "happiness", "majority", "vexing", "undulation", "periphery", "exultant",
      "jeering", "trampoline","weirdo","blondie","bowtie","controller","completion"]
index=random.randint(0, len(wordlist) - 1) #selects a random integer from range of list
correctword=wordlist[index]
#declaring variables
maxGuesses = len(correctword) + 5
guessCounter = 0
sofar= []
win = False 
wordLetters = 0
whileloop = False
mainLoop = True
guessList = []

for char in correctword:
    sofar.append("_") #makes the list have only Dashes
    wordLetters = wordLetters + 1
#display the length of wordlist (done in loops)
# print(sofar)
# print(" ".join(sofar)) #joins the elements in sofar into a string

print("Hangman game! Let's begin")
print("*+_______________________________________________________+*\n")

def findInd(string, char):
    return [i for i, letter in enumerate(string) if letter == char]
    #This will be called to find all indexes of letter in CorrectWord. 

def find_letter(list):
    if not list:          
        return 0

    elif list[0] == l:  #check first element here for guessed letter
        return True

    elif find_letter(list[1:]):  # checked the first element, skip it and return the other elements of the list
        return True

    else: 
        return False

while (mainLoop == True):
    print ('The word to guess: ',  " ".join(sofar), wordLetters, "letters long")
    letter = raw_input("guess a letter: ")
    guessCounter = guessCounter +1

    l = letter
    if (find_letter(guessList) == True):
        print("You already guessed that letter!")
        guessCounter = guessCounter -1
        continue
    else:
        guessList.append(letter) #Here is where it declares "NonType Error"

    for char in correctword:
        if letter == char:
            print ("good guess")
            whileloop = True
            mainLoop = True

    if whileloop == False:
        print ("That letter is not in the word! Guess again. \n")
        mainLoop = True

    #will skip this loop if letter is wrong
    while (whileloop == True):
        for num in (findInd(correctword, letter)): #returns list of indexes
            sofar[num] = letter #Replaces the places in sofar with char
        whileloop = False;  
            #if (letter == char): 
            #index = correctword.find(letter)
            #sofar[index] = letter

    print("*+_______________________________________________________+*\n") 

    count = sofar.count("_")

    if count == 0:
        win = True
        break #exits the main while loop

    guessList = guessList.sort()
    print ("you have guessed these letters: ", guessList)
    print ("Guesses left: ", (maxGuesses-guessCounter))
    if guessCounter == maxGuesses:
        break #User has used all the guesses and not won.

#outside of While loop

if win == True:
    print ("CONGRADULATIONS! You won. The word was ", correctword)
    print (" Thanks for playing")
else:
    print ("heh you lose... Try again some time")
```

It points to the line "guessList.append(letter)". It must return none because when I print guessList, I get none. But I'm not doing the classic guessList = guessList.append(letter). Also, oddly enough, it runs once where it will print guessList = None, and then the second time (when it checks for repetition of character in guessList it crashes.

Comment: Please give us a [mcve] that actually reproduces the error. If we assume that `guessList = []`, there is no error. The problem in your actual code is that somewhere, you set `guessList` to `None`. So that's the part you need to fix—and that part isn't in the code you've shown us, so we can't help you.

Comment: You never defined `guessList`. So you should get a `NameError`.

Comment: Don't use global variables. `find_letter` should have `l` as argument.

Comment: @Daniel: [How about any of these?](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bpython%5d%20AttributeError%3a%20%27NoneType%27%20object%20has%20no%20attribute%20%27append%27)

Comment: @l'L'l: look at abarnert's comment. It's a problem, that is not shown in the code.

Comment: Right above I have declared  guessCounter = 0
sofar= []
win = False 
wordLetters = 0
whileloop = False
mainLoop = True
guessList = []

Comment: I'm going to edit the original code to display the full file, just will be quite long. I have declared the guessList @Daniel which is why it's so frustrating to find articles about guessList = guessList.append() because it doesn't apply to mine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your whole code, the error is clear. You don't have the classic append error, but the same mistake:

```
guessList = guessList.sort()
```

`sort` sorts the list inplace and returns `None`.

Comment: Ah you hero thank you. Ofc it happens below it and that's why it can run once

Answer (score 0):

As per @Daniel's comment to your question. You'll get `NameError` if you didn't declare a variable. According to me you've declared `guessList` as a global variable. Sometimes python doesn't recognize `global variables` properly. So, you need to specify in the function that it is a global variable by using `global` key word.

So your code should have `global guessList` in the functions like this

```
def main():
    global guessList
    while (mainLoop == True):
       print ('The word to guess: ',  " ".join(sofar), wordLetters, "letters long")
       letter = raw_input("guess a letter: ")
       guessCounter = guessCounter +1
       l = letter
       if (find_letter(guessList) == True):
            print("You already guessed that letter!")
            guessCounter = guessCounter -1
            continue
       else:
            guessList.append(letter)
```

**If this is not the case then the only possible errors might be either either one of the following.**

1. You might have initialized `guessList` as `None`. I so reassign as `guessList=[]`.
2. You might've not imported the variable from the module, If you are using multiple modules and referring each other. If so,

   - import it as `from module import guessList` ***or***
   - import it as `import module` and use as `module.guessList`.
3. You might've not declared and defined the variable if so declare and define it as `guessList=[]`.

Comment: So I should put my while loop in a "def main():" in order to have guessList be global? Because right now it can access guessList outside of while loop, it just seems to return it as "none"

Comment: No it was just an example. You didn't explain the program. So I gave all possible solution.

Comment: Please post the question with minimal details and ask for answers. Else the answers will be on user's guess.